# How to show that $\prod_{d|n}(x^{\frac{n}{d}}-1)^{\mu(d)}= \prod_{d|n}(x^{{n}}-1)^{\mu(d/n)}?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Prove that $\Phi_n(x)= \prod_{d|n}(x^d-1)^{\mu(n/d)}$

**My attempt** : :
By using  Mobius inversion formula    that   if  $f(n)$  is defined  for all  nonnegative  integers  and $F(n)= \sum_{d|n} f(d)$ ,then $$f(n)= \sum_{d|n} \mu(d) F(n/d)$$

I got $\Phi_n(x)= \prod_{d|n}(x^{\frac{n}{d}}-1)^{\mu(d)}$
After that  im unable to proceed further

**My confusion** : How  to  show that    $\prod_{d|n}(x^{\frac{n}{d}}-1)^{\mu(d)}= \prod_{d|n}(x^{{n}}-1)^{\mu(d/n)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a few errors, should be

$$\prod_{d|n}(x^{\frac{n}{d}}-1)^{\mu(d)}= \prod_{d|n}(x^{{d}}-1)^{\mu(n/d)}$$

where all that is done is interchanging $d$ and $n/d$